# Fastest way to get the number in tail of a string

Tags: algorithm, string

Given that we have this kind of string "XXXXXXX XXXXX 756", "XXXXX XXXXXX35665", (X is a character), which is the fasted way to get the number in the end of string?

EDIT: well, this is just-for-fun question. Solve this is quite simple, but I want to know the fastest algorithm to archive this. Rock it on!

Comment: "Faster" how? How is the string represented? What language? Do you need the number parsed to an integer (you didn't specify that)?

Comment: Fastest how? Given what constraints? There's no real question here.

Answer (score 4):

In C, a quick O(n), one-pass algorithm (does not see negative signs) is :

```
int suffixedNumber(char* string) {
  int result = 0;
  char ch;
  while (ch = *string++)
    // Check whether <= '9' first, because most characters are > '9'.
    result = (ch <= '9' && ch >= '0') ? 10*result + (ch - '0') : 0;
  return result;
}
```

If you're alright with `goto`s, you can get a ≈20% faster algorithm that (in order of importance) :

1. returns -1 when there is no number at the end of `string`
2. avoids checking for end-of-string when `ch >= '0'`
3. avoids resetting `result` to zero when `ch` is nonnumeric
4. avoids multiplying `result` by ten when a number starts
5. avoids setting `result` to zero at the beginning

```
int suffixedNumber(char* string) {
  int result;
  char ch;

  nonnumber: // STATE: Waiting for the start of a number.
  ch = *string++;
  if (ch > '9') goto nonnumber; // Decide this boundary first (> '9' most frequent)
  if (ch < '0') {               // Decide this boundary next
    if (ch == '\0') return -1;  // Decide this boundary last  ('\0' least frequent)
    goto nonnumber;
  }
  result = ch - '0';

  number:    // STATE: In the middle of a number.
  ch = *string++;
  if (ch > '9') goto nonnumber;    // Decide this boundary first (> '9' most frequent)
  if (ch < '0') {                  // Decide this boundary next
    if (ch == '\0') return result; // Decide this boundary last  ('\0' least frequent)
    goto nonnumber;
  }
  result = 10*result + (ch - '0');

  goto number;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Assuming the text can be streamed in reverse order (a reasonable assumption since strings in most languages are backed by an array of characters with `O(1)` access), construct the number by reading the text backwards until you hit a character that is not a digit or the text has been consumed entirely.

```
numDigits = 0
number = 0

while(numDigits <> length and characterAt[length - numDigits] is a digit)
   number = number + (parseCharacterAt[length - numDigits] * (10 ^ numDigits))
   numDigits = numDigits + 1
end while

if(numDigits is 0)
  Error ("No digits at the end")

else return number
```

Note: (10 ^ numDigits) can be trivially optimized with another variable.

Comment: If you optimize `10 ^ numDigits`, you can make numDigits count backwards (starting at length - 1) to avoid the subtraction, which would be even faster.

Answer (score 0):

Without knowing language or context, if the number of digits or characters is fixed length a simple substring would do, otherwise a regex matching consecutive digits (i.e. `/\d+/`).

Probably some faster algorithm if you drop down to C++ levels, but I favour expressiveness.

Answer (score 0):

use regular expression:

```
/^.+?(\d+)$/
```

and take first match capture group (\d+)

**Edit:**
if you can't use regular expressions, **FASTEST WAY** will be something like this:

```
i = string.len
while i > 0:
  break if string[i].isNotNum
  i--
end

out = substring(string, i,string.len)
```

Answer (score 0):

I would just call the lastIndexOf('X') of your String object and proceed from there.  Not backward looping mess.

Comment: X is a character, it can be anything from a-z, X does not mean 'X'

Answer (score 0):

Stating the problem:

> We want to find the index of the last non-digit character

Reflexion:

> This implies that we check that each character after this point is a digit, which means we will need to perform at least O(k) comparison where `k` is the number of digits at the end of the string

Implementation:

> Linear backward search, possibly involving bitwise trickery to "vectorize" the operations (comparing multiple characters at once) or leveraging a multithreading effort.

Answer (score 0):

definitely dont use regex - way too slow. Just loop backwards until you find the first non numeric character:

```
string s = "XXXXX XXXXXX35665";
int i = s.Length;
while (--i >= 0 && Char.IsNumber(s[i]));
s=s.Substring(i + 1);
```

should do the trick.. ??

Answer (score 0):

extracting tail number

```
    str="XXXXXx....XXXX333"; 
    parseInt(str.match(/\d*$/)
```

if float point wanted then

```
    parseInt(str.match(/\d|\.*$/)
```

increment tail number:

```
    str.replace(/(\d*)$/,function(){return parseInt(arguments[0])+1;})
```